# Embadding Python in .NET - how to embad (specific) python object?

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I try to embad this python code

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

in .NET as follows:

```
using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic spacy = Py.Import("spacy");
            dynamic nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm");      
            dynamic doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion");                       
            dynamic ent = doc.ents;            // Here I get `ent.text`
            //dynamic label = ent.label_;       // Here I expect to get `ent.label_`     
            return ents;                    
        }
```

Now I need to get ent.label_ as well.
I tried it by adding this line:

```
dynamic label = ents.label_;
```

But I get this error: `"Python.Runtime.PythonException: "AttributeError : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'label_'"`

I expect following output:

Apple ORG, U.K. GPE, $1 billion MONEY

How can I find and output `ent.label_`?

Answer (score 1):

Here the answer:

```
scope.Exec(
                        "import spacy\n" +
                        "nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')\n" +
                        "doc = nlp("TODO: Your text")\n" +
                        "for ent in doc.ents:\n" +
                        "   Entity = ent.text\n" +
                        "for ent in doc.ents:\n" +
                        "   Label = ent.label_\n" 
                    );
```